# Mathjax-Catalysts on reaction arrows

Tags: support

How can mathjax be used with \ce to show reaction conditions and catalysts on the arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\ce{LiK + e- ->[this?]}$

Use square brackets immediately  after the arrow. Eg `$\ce{ A ->[above][below] B}$` gives $\ce{ A ->[above][below] B}$. You may omit the brackets for the below-arrow bit if you wish.

There's more info on this and all other mhchem features in the [documentation](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf)

Comment: Do you how to enable mchem on sites (e.g. Mathematica.SE) that don't have it installed by default?  \usepackage doesn't seem to work.  I've seen the solution somewhere but figured it was such an easy thing to remember I wouldn't have to bookmark it.....ugh.

Comment: @bobthechemist `\require{mhchem}` should work for a single page (Other [extensions](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html) can be used this way too). Otherwise you can make a meta post for it to be enabled on all pages for the site if you have a good enough case for it.

Comment: @ManishEarth Offtopic but, is $\ce{LiK}$ a real compound? I head diatomic species like $\ce{Li2}$ and $\ce{K2}$ exist and are explained by MOT, so why not $\ce{LiK}$?